# Integration of Stripe into Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am relatively new to AngularJS and am building a controller that looks to capture the token generated from stripe when a user completes the form that is written in HTML and fires this back to the DB by way of a factory that is injected into the controller. I will also need to display the token as a custom name string (so, not the token string) in the view after the card has been processed.

I am struggling with my javascript at the moment, whereby I simply don't know where to start. I have a basic check in place to ensure that the form is filled in, but after that, I am a little stuck as to what to think of next.

I am working on this all weekend and any guidance and help to get the ball rolling and thinking in the correct way, would be much appreciated.

here is the controller:

```
.controller('ControllerName',
        ['$scope', '$http', 'NewCardFactory', 'UserAccountFactory',
            function ($scope, $http, NewCardFactory, UserAccountFactory) {

            'use strict';   

            $scope.sent = false;

            $scope.cardPayment = function (client, server) {

                if (client.error) {
                    $scope.sent = false;
                    $scope.message = "Sorry, the details you have entered are not correct, please try again";
                } else {

    //basically, after here, I am totally lost!!! I got some help for the below, but I am lost with what this needs to do next. 

                    $scope.cardDetails = {};
                    var card = new Card(
                            {
                                user_id: user_id,
                                token: token,
                                cardholder: name_of_user_on_card,
                                friendly_name: friendly_name
                            }
                        );

                    card.$save();
                }

            };

        }]);
```

I find this stuff quite difficult, I sort of understand that JavaScript is all about objects and in the

```
if(client.error) { this stuff in here is an object} else...
```

if this right?

As you can see, I need some assistance, so anyone wanting to do a good deed this weekend and help this UX-Designer, newly turned Front-End Dev break through the programming wall he is experiencing, I would be eternally grateful.

Thanks in advance.

P.S if you need anymore code to see other pieces of the puzzle, just ask.

Comment: Hi, what's the actual specific problem you're having? What isn't working? Conceptually, you seem to be in the right space - but I'm not sure what you're actually asking

Comment: Also, the statement inside an "if" isn't an object in itself - it's just a JavaScript statement. However, you could define an object within the scope of the "if" statement, or perform an operation on some object that is defined in the "if" statement's parent scope.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. The problem I am having is integrating stripe into Angularjs by way of setting the controller correctly to handle the data response from the form that the users will complete. I have found a tutorial on stripe about building custom payment forms, so I'm making a little more progress than before.  But the workflow should be enter details > press submit > sent to stripe who return us a token > token gets sent to our server.